# How to access the kubelet on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following the example here for setting up a GPU enabled cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine. 
https://engineering.bitnami.com/articles/using-gpus-with-kubernetes.html

But what does step 3 mean?

```
Step 3: Configure Each Kubelet To Use The NVIDIA GPU
```

How is that different to running the steps on the Node? How do I access the kubelet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kubelet is not accessible on GKE. Instead, follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus) provided by Google on how to configure GPUs on GKE.